# C++: Member function pointer parameter with variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to write a brief unit tester for a project I am working on.

This test passes if the given function throws a certain kind of exception:

```
template <class Exception, class Return, class... Args>
bool throws(std::string s, Return(*fn)(Args...), Args... args)
{
  try
  {
    fn(args...);
  }
  catch (Exception& e)
  {
    return output(s, true);
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    return output(s, false);
  }
  return output(s, false);
}
```

Using it would look something like this:

```
throws<int>("Testing: Throws int", &foo);
```

And that works great.  But now I'm trying to write a similar function that will work with member functions of a class.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
template <class Exception, class Object, class Return, class... Args>
bool throws(std::string s, Object& o, Return(Object::*fn)(Args...), Args... args)
{
  // ...
  (o.*fn)(args...);
  // ...
}

template <class Exception, class Object, class Return, class... Args>
bool throws(std::string s, const Object& o, Return(Object::*fn)(Args...) const, Args... args)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Which should look something like this when used:

```
Bar<int> b1(5), b2(2);
typedef Bar<int>& (Bar<int>::*fn)(const Bar<int>&);
typedef Bar<int> (Bar<int>::*const_fn)(const Bar<int>&) const;

fn foo = &Bar<int>::foo;
const_fn const_foo = &Bar<int>::const_foo;

throws<int>("Testing member function", b1, foo, b2);
throws<int>("Testing const member function", b1, const_foo, b2);
```

But when I do this, I get "no matching function call" for both of these throws() functions.  Specifically:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘throws(const char [30], Bar<int>&, Bar<int> (Bar<int>::*&)(const Bar<int>&)const, const Bar<int>&)
```

And a similar one for the non-const version.

I noticed a few consts that were different, so I tried throwing in some const_cast's where I use the function, but no dice.  This is the first time I've used member function pointers and variadic templates, (at all, let alone at the same time,) so I definitely could have missed something...  anyone more experienced than me have any ideas?

The only thing I haven't been able to account for is the `(Bar<int>::*&)`.  The & at the end of that doesn't match the call... but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?

**EDIT :** As requested, my Bar class:

```
template <class T>
class Bar
{
private:
  T _data;
public:
  Bar (const int i) : _data(i) {}
  Bar const_foo (const Bar& other) const
  {
    if (_data != other._data)
    {
      throw _data;
    }
    return Bar(_data);
  }
  Bar& foo (const Bar& other)
  {
    if (_data != other._data)
    {
      throw _data;
    }
    return *this;
  }
};
```

And the full errors:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:111:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘throws(const char [24], Bar<int>&, Bar<int>& (Bar<int>::*&)(const Bar<int>&), Bar<int>&)’
test.cpp:111:53: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:31:6: note: template<class Exception, class Return, class ... Args> bool throws(std::string, Return (*)(Args ...), Args ...)
test.cpp:53:6: note: template<class Exception, class Object, class Return, class ... Args> bool throws(std::string, Object&, Return (Object::*)(Args ...), Args ...)
test.cpp:75:6: note: template<class Exception, class Object, class Return, class ... Args> bool throws(std::string, const Object&, Return (Object::*)(Args ...)const, Args ...)
test.cpp:112:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘throws(const char [30], Bar<int>&, Bar<int> (Bar<int>::*&)(const Bar<int>&)const, Bar<int>&)’
test.cpp:112:65: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:31:6: note: template<class Exception, class Return, class ... Args> bool throws(std::string, Return (*)(Args ...), Args ...)
test.cpp:53:6: note: template<class Exception, class Object, class Return, class ... Args> bool throws(std::string, Object&, Return (Object::*)(Args ...), Args ...)
test.cpp:75:6: note: template<class Exception, class Object, class Return, class ... Args> bool throws(std::string, const Object&, Return (Object::*)(Args ...)const, Args ...)
```

Comment: A general tip; you could look at std::bind to make the code a bit easier to manage.

Comment: The compiler can't deduce the type of the function pointer you're passing.

Comment: @0x499602D2: As far as I can tell, the only difference between the different throws() functions is that the member function ones require a calling object, and the syntax for member function pointers is a bit different.  So why did the first example work perfectly?

Comment: What do you mean why did the first example work? You said "when I do this, I get "no matching function call" for **both** of these `throws()` functions" ...

Comment: I mean the first example that works on non-member functions.

Comment: I likely missed something obvious, but [is **this** similar](http://ideone.com/42Fp6L) to what you're trying to do?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, almost exactly!  That's really interesting, I didn't realize that you could pass function pointers as rvalue references.  I'll definitely have to look into that more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you use the non-member version with a function taking zero arguments. I believe your code fails when you try to pass arguments, not when you change it to take a member function. By changing it to take a member function and passing an argument in the same step, you obfuscated the real reason for the failure. I believe your code would work if you tried it with a member function taking zero arguments. And I believe your non-member version would fail if you tried to use it with a function taking one or more arguments.

```
template <class Exception, class Object, class Return, class... Args>
bool throws(std::string s, Object& o, Return(Object::*fn)(Args...), Args... args)
```

Here you are telling the compiler that the types of the fourth argument to `throws` and the first argument to the function pointer must be *exactly the same*.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘throws(const char [24], Bar<int>&,
       Bar<int>& (Bar<int>::*&)(const Bar<int>&), Bar<int>&)’
```

The compiler is telling you that the fourth argument to `throws` and the first argument to the function pointer are different, so it can't find a declaration of `throws` which matches. Your template can't match because that would mean `Args...` would have to deduce as `const Bar<int>&` and `Bar<int>&` at the same time, and those are two different types.

The solution provided in a comment by @WhozCraig works because the function type and the argument types are deduced independently. His solution passes the function pointer by universal reference, but that is incidental; it could also take the function pointer by `const` lvalue reference, or by value.

```
template <class Exception, class Func, class... Args>
bool throws(std::string s, Func fn, Args&&... args)
{ /*...*/ }

template <class Exception, class Object, class MemFunc, class... Args>
bool throws(std::string s, Object& o, MemFunc fn, Args&&... args)
{ /*...*/ }
```

Unfortunately with this approach you may run into situations where the overload is ambiguous. The easy solution to this would be to rename the member version `memberThrows`. The more complicated version would be to use tag dispatch or SFINAE (I would prefer the former in this case).

```
template <class Exception, class Func, class... Args>
bool throwsHelper(std::false_type, std::string s, Func fn, Args&&... args)
{ /*...*/ }

template <class Exception, class MemFunc, class Object, class... Args>
bool throwsHelper(std::true_type, std::string s, MemFunc fn, Object&& o, Args&&... args)
{ /*...*/ }

template <class Exception, class Func, class... Args>
bool throws(std::string s, Func fn, Args&&... args)
{
    using isMember = typename std::is_member_pointer<Func>::type;
    return throwsHelper(isMember(), s, fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Notice that I had to change the order of the arguments to the member version to allow uniform calling in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Bar<int>::const_foo` is a `const` member function and it has the return type `Bar<int>` (and not a reference). Post more code if this is not the issue.

Comment: It is.  It would cause a compile error if it didn't match, correct?

Comment: I guess so... can you post the definition of `Bar` class? And the line `throws<SizeException>("Testing member function", b1, foo, b2);` compiles fine, the problem appears in `throws<SizeException>("Testing const member function", b1, const_foo, b2);`, is this correct? And don't you get a compile error? At least that's what I understood.

Comment: I get the same compile error for both functions.  (I should have specified that; I'll edit my original post.)  I can post more code if that would help.

Comment: Just post the definitions of your functions `foo` and `const_foo` inside the `Bar<T>` class.

Comment: What puzzles me is why `const char [10]` is the first argument of `throws` in the error, when it should be a `std::string`. And where did that `10` came from!?

Comment: Sorry, I copied an error from code that was slightly different than what I posted.  I've updated the original post with the Bar class and the full (updated) errors.

Comment: I think there are some issues with your code, first of all, you cannot use a pointer-to-member-to-function outside the class, as the function depends on the instantiation, (unless the function is `static`). The error may come from this fact, template errors are a pain and I cannot figure our any other reason now.

Comment: Just try to make your test function a member of the class and see what's happening.

Comment: You can use a pointer-to-member-function outside the class (provided the member function is `public`). The reason for the `const char[10]` is that that is the type of the argument passed, before implicit conversions are applied.